# jquery Datatables and css not rendering in mvc 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, datatables

I have a simple view page, trying to render jquery datable for my view in MVC4.

My view [Admin.cshtml]

```
<div style="width:90%; margin:0 auto;">
    <table id="myTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Practice Name</th>
                <th>Practice Address</th>
                <th>Practice Email</th>
                <th>Practice Telephone</th>
                <th>Created Date</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>
```

and my reference to css and js for jquery datatables are underneath the  section:

```
 <link type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/css/jQuery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/> 
@section Scripts{
 <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/jQuery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#myTable').dataTable({
                "ajax": {
                    "url": "/Home/Admin",
                    "type": "GET",
                    "datatype": "json"
                },
                "columns": [
                    { "data": "Practice_Name", "autowidth": true },
                    { "data": "Practice_Address", "autowidth": true },
                    { "data": "Practice_Email", "autowidth": true },
                    { "data": "Practice_Telephone", "autowidth": true },
                    { "data": "Created_Date", "autowidth": true }
                ]
            });
        });
    </script>
 }
```

and in my Controller, i have a simple GET section:

```
       public ActionResult Admin()
        {
            var data = db.Practices.ToList();
            return Json(new { data = data }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

But, when i run this application, i am getting my resultset like this

[image]

Where am i going wrong ?

Comment: Try using just the array of objects.  You are sending an object which has the property `data` whose value is the array.

Comment: there's no issue in getting my data, as you see in the resultset, it's just the way it's getting rendered in my view, which, its not picking the jquery datatable and css..

Comment: From the image it looks like it is spitting out the entire json as a single entry in the grid rather than populating the various grid boxes individually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your controller method name:

`public ActionResult Admin()` to `public ActionResult GetAdminData()`

Create another action method:

`[Authorize] 
public ActionResult Admin () => View();`

Modify your JavaScript code:

`"url": "/Home/Admin"` to `"url": "/Home/GetAdminData"`

And update CDN links because they are too old:

https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css
https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js

Why is all of this needed?

1. When you navigate to /Home/Admin your return View (the Admin.cshtml)
2. Your view contains some custom JavaScript logic which will try to fetch a list of items from the database (your `GetAdminData` method)
3. `GetAdminData` returns JSON which can be used by `DataTables` in order to show your desired content on the page.

Comment: this doesn't solve the issue, it's rendering the same way, and no changes..

Comment: Can you provide us more code? For example, Admin.cshtml code and the method which returns it.

Comment: Thanks  @ciubotariu-florin, but all the code is posted above, my whole .cshtml and my controller..

Comment: The problem is not solvable at the moment because we do not have enough information about your classes and what you want to do. As far as I can see, Admin.cshtml and Javascript are never returned by any method.

Comment: Actually, i got the same code from this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z5CIMlLNOe4

Comment: Show us all the HomeController and all the .cshtml, not just snippets.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194961/discussion-between-ron-and-ciubotariu-florin).

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the help @Ciubotariu Florin, your steps worked fine for me and thanks for your time in chatting privately, to help me fix this issue. Much appreciated. !! Problem Resolved !!